# Triggering an event based on changes in the textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need a hidden div to show up the moment one of two things happen

1. The user presses "@", and then press any other non-whitespace character
2. The user copies and pastes "@xxx" into the system, where @xxx is any string that starts with "@"

I am having quite a bit of issues with this in jQuery - any help would be much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [textchange plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) by Zurb, that adds a textchange event which you can bind to.

What you can do then:

```
var prev;
$('#tf1').bind('textchange', function() {
   var cur = $(this).val();
   //TODO compare prev & curr, check you condition
   prev = cur;
});
```